# ufw rule updates don't take effect

Tags: networking, ufw

I decided to close some ports on my machine running Ubuntu 12.04 so I closed them via:

```
sudo ufw deny <port num>
```

I tried closing all ports, including port 80 to see if it would work but I'm still able to surf the net. I then I did:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

but still I have internet connection. Also, when I scan my machine with:

```
nmap -v -sT localhost
```

it still shows these ports as open. How is that possible if the status of ufw is active and I close port 80? Does that mean that I am not enabling the new rules correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running something like `sudo ufw deny 80` means to block *incoming* connections to port 80 on your machine. It does not block *outgoing* connections on port 80. If you want to block HTTP, you'll need to block outgoing connections on port 80. Additionally, rules in UFW take effect immediately assuming UFW is enabled (check `sudo ufw status` for the current status and rules).

UFW doesn't block access to ports from `localhost`; if it did so, there would be no reason to have that service installed, as nothing would be able to access it.

Note that UFW has a fallback policy for each category of connections (incoming, outgoing, and routed) if there is no policy to handle that connection. see the "Default" line when running `sudo ufw status verbose`. By default, (I believe) all incoming and routed connections are blocked, and outgoing connections are allowed.